# save backbone nested models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have backbone nested model:

```
var ModelA = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        title: "",
        modelB: null
    }
});

var ModelB = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        text: ""
    }
});
```

I want ModelA to save itself everytime ModelB's member `text` is changed. How can I do it?
Is it appropriate to assign event listeners inside different model?
How can I unbind those events later?

(I cannot use the Backbone Relational plugin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdiaz/Rdttb/) shows an example of the binding on `ModelA` constructor. The event binding will be discarded when the instance of `ModelB` it's destroyed by the garbage collector.

Answer (score 0):

in ModelA definition :

```
initialize:function(modelB){
  this.set("modelB",modelB);
  modelB.on("change:text",this.save(),this);
}
```

( not tested )